# jQueryUI range slider showing progress

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, range, jquery-ui-slider

I have a `range: true` slider and want to show progress like the progress bar between the two handles of the slider. Kind of like this, http://jsfiddle.net/cG8qB/, except this will be happening in between the two handles of my slider instead of the whole slider like in that example and I only need the color updating instead of a slider handle.

So basically, I want to change the color of the part in between the two slider handles to something like the behavior of a `range: min` slider where the "min" is the left handle of my slider and the handle of this `range: min` slider is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in the original jsfiddle the whole time

This does the trick.

`$("#slider").find('.ui-widget-header').css('width', x + '%');`

This also works.

`$("#slider div").css('width', x + '%');`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide the handle by add the following css rule:

```
.ui-slider-handle { display: none }
```

Then you may want to disable the slider to prevent it from being changed by the user, i.e. adding `disabled: true` to the initiation.

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/cG8qB/8/.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking for that to be overlayed onto a range slider though, in between the two handles.

Comment: No, imagine the range slider here, http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range. Now instead of the orange part, I want the animation shown here, http://jsfiddle.net/william/cG8qB/8/.

Comment: not really... are you looking for a progress bar like this? http://jsfiddle.net/william/cG8qB/16/

Comment: I'm wanting that to be only in the segment in between the two handles of a larger slider